# Unable to run temporal workflow from terminal

Tags: java, temporal-workflow

I am using temporal for running workflows.  I have created a jar with my app. and running the below cmd from terminal `java -jar build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Getting the below error when trying to run the above cmd:-

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
        at io.temporal.api.workflowservice.v1.WorkflowServiceGrpc$WorkflowServiceBlockingStub.getSystemInfo(WorkflowServiceGrpc.java:4139)
        at io.temporal.serviceclient.SystemInfoInterceptor.getServerCapabilitiesOrThrow(SystemInfoInterceptor.java:95)
        at io.temporal.serviceclient.ChannelManager.lambda$getServerCapabilities$3(ChannelManager.java:330)
        at io.temporal.internal.retryer.GrpcRetryer.retryWithResult(GrpcRetryer.java:60)
        at io.temporal.serviceclient.ChannelManager.connect(ChannelManager.java:297)
        at io.temporal.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceStubsImpl.connect(WorkflowServiceStubsImpl.java:161)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at io.temporal.internal.WorkflowThreadMarker.lambda$protectFromWorkflowThread$1(WorkflowThreadMarker.java:83)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.connect(Unknown Source)
        at io.temporal.worker.WorkerFactory.start(WorkerFactory.java:210)
        at com.hok.furlenco.workflow.refundStatusSync.RefundStatusSyncSaga.createWorkFlow(RefundStatusSyncSaga.java:41)
        at com.hok.furlenco.workflow.refundStatusSync.RefundStatusSyncSaga.main(RefundStatusSyncSaga.java:17)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnsupportedAddressTypeException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:146)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:157)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkRemote(SocketChannelImpl.java:816)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:839)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:91)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:88)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.connect(SocketUtils.java:88)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:322)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:248)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1342)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:533)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:54)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.connect(WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.java:157)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:61)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$9.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:538)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The app works fine when trying to run it from IDE:-
The temporal server is running as a docker container in my local:-

[image]

**

- RefundStatusSyncSaga.java

**

```
/ gRPC stubs wrapper that talks to the local docker instance of temporal service.
    WorkflowServiceStubs service = WorkflowServiceStubs.newLocalServiceStubs();
    // client that can be used to start and signal workflows
    WorkflowClient client = WorkflowClient.newInstance(service);

    // worker factory that can be used to create workers for specific task queues
    WorkerFactory factory = WorkerFactory.newInstance(client);

    // Worker that listens on a task queue and hosts both workflow and activity implementations.
    Worker worker = factory.newWorker(TASK_QUEUE);

    // Workflows are stateful. So you need a type to create instances.
    worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(RefundSyncWorkflowImpl.class);

    // Activities are stateless and thread safe. So a shared instance is used.
    RefundStatusActivities tripBookingActivities = new RefundStatusActivitiesImpl();
    worker.registerActivitiesImplementations(tripBookingActivities);

    // Start all workers created by this factory.
    factory.start();
    System.out.println("Worker started for task queue: " + TASK_QUEUE);

    // now we can start running instances of our saga - its state will be persisted
    WorkflowOptions options = WorkflowOptions.newBuilder().setTaskQueue(TASK_QUEUE)
            .setWorkflowId("1")
            .setWorkflowIdReusePolicy( WorkflowIdReusePolicy.WORKFLOW_ID_REUSE_POLICY_REJECT_DUPLICATE)
            .setCronSchedule("* * * * *")
            .build();
    RefundSyncWorkflow refundSyncWorkflow = client.newWorkflowStub(RefundSyncWorkflow.class, options);
    refundSyncWorkflow.syncRefundStatus();
```

The complete code can be seen here -> https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/temporal-sample

Comment: Which version of Java are you using in command line? Can you please provide the complete output of `java -version`

Comment: Also, how do you specify your Temporal server host to your worker configuration? That's probably in RefundStatusSyncSaga.java... Could it be that your code expect an environment variable that is set in your IDE but not in your command line?

Comment: @James - Thanks for your reply. I have put the code snippet for 'RefundStatusSyncSaga' and also pushed the full code to git for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I also come across this and I dig into the jar debugging. I found that in this check `public static InetSocketAddress checkAddress(SocketAddress sa)`, the SocketAddress will become `/xxx:443`(my original addr is xxx:443). Then the validation check failed... I still don't know how to solve it.

**update**: one solution could be found here https://community.temporal.io/t/unable-to-run-temporal-workflow-from-jar/6607